# Where is it best to put the "when" of a sentence?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, time, adverb-position, adverbials

1. John **yesterday** went to the store to buy eggs.
2. John went to the store **yesterday** to buy eggs.
3. John went to the store to buy eggs **yesterday**.

Comment: The most common usage, you have missed: John went to the store yesterday to buy eggs.

Comment: @Lambie but that's option #2...

Comment: Can you explain why that's the "right" one.

Comment: Whoops, so it is. Sorry. Typically, the time (yesterday, today, last week, a date, three days ago) goes after the action verb. However, it can go at the beginning  and at the end of a sentence (utterance). It would not go right after the subject except exceptionally. :)

Comment: I see it go after the subject like this: The United States Senate today passed a law prohibiting... Is that right?

Comment: The first variant sounds unidiomatic, but the other three variants (including _Yesterday, ..'\-_)  are all possible and can give different emphases.

Comment: I see it go after the subject like this: The United States Senate today passed a law prohibiting... Is that right? ... Yes, but this is in a very different register from your first examples. Those are conversational to unmarked; this is formal / quite highbrow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the reason we usually position adverbial ***yesterday*** at the beginning or end of OP's example sentence (whereas we'd put an adverb like ***willingly*** immediately before or after the relevant verb ***went***) is because it modifies ***the entire sentence***.

See [this earlier ELU answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/380682/2637) about the difference between "sentence" and a "manner" adverbs. But at the end of the day it's largely down to individual stylistic choices.

Comment: You're trying to sell a temporal adverb as a sentence adverb like _hopefully_? Do you think topicality might have something to do with it?

Comment: Wherever it is positioned, "yesterday" is tightly integrated into clause structure and hence is modifying the VP. It is not like speech act-related adjuncts, compare "Frankly, I think we could do", where "frankly" is a supplement with the main clause as its semantic anchor.

Comment: @BillJ, KarlG: It seems to me any one (or *pair* of) the elements *to the store, to buy eggs,* and *yesterday* could be removed. And maybe it's just my personal take on a likely context, but I'd say *yesterday* is the least "tightly bound" component (going somewhere to buy something being a sorta "identifiable / familiar" activity). If the time was particularly important, I'd probably "promote" it to the *start* of the utterance (as well as stressing it) - but if it wasn't, I'd just tack it on the end (He did something yesterday). To me, the latter case just seems easier to imagine arising.